# Find all changed values in update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query that updates a targettable  from a sourcetable but only if the field in the targettable is empty or contains the value '1899-12-30'.

Targettable and sourcetable consist of solely nvarchar fields. I have no influence on the design of these tables. Any string that looks like a date should still be considered a string.

```
UPDATE targettable SET
 columnA=IIF(len(t.columnA) = 0 OR t.columnA = '1899-12-30', s.columnA,t.ColumnA)
,columnB=IIF(len(t.columnB) = 0 OR t.columnB = '1899-12-30', s.columnB,t.columnB)
,columnC=IIF(len(t.columnC) = 0 OR t.columnC = '1899-12-30', s.columnC,t.columnC)
FROM sourcetable s
LEFT JOIN targettable t
```

t.ColumnA = '' (empty string) so it **gets updated** with s.columnA which contains 'foo'
t.ColumnB = 'something' so it **does not get updated**
t.ColumnC = '1899-12-30' so it **gets updated** with s.columnC which contains '1900-01-01'

Now what I would like is to get the values that changed and store them like this

```
TIME_OF_CHANGE | COLUMNNAME| OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE
2021-5-20 14:12 | ColumnA |  | foo
2021-5-20 14:12 | ColumnC | 1899-12-30| 1900-01-01
```

The updatequery works like a charm but I cannot figure out how to transform this data so that it is written  as
`TIME_OF_CHANGE | COLUMNNAME| OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE`

Comment: `len(t.columnA) = 0 OR t.columnA = '1899-12-30'` doesn't make a lot of sense. `LEN` returns the number of characters in a string, nut you then provide a string literal for a date, meaning that (presumably) `columnA` is a date and time value; dates don't have a length, they aren't string. Unless you are storing date (and time) values as a `varchar`? If so, you should be fixing your design.

Comment: Unfortunately, dates are stored as varchars. These dates are generated by Delphi programs so that is why the field is filled with '1899-12-30' instead of NULL or an empty string.
I have done a fair bit of protesting regarding this abuse of datatypes but this is what I have to work with.

Comment: I will then, repeat my statement: you need to fix that. Never store data and time values as a `varchar`. You will easily have behavioural and performance issues down the line.

Comment: I agree. But it's not gonna happen. Not my call.  Not relevant to the question either I think.

Comment: It actually is, sort of. You want to (dynamically?) unpivot all your columns into one column here; that means mixing data types into a single column which can rarely be a good idea too. So,unfortunately, you're going to need to cast *all* of your columns to a `(n)varchar` to do this, which is really far from ideal. It can easily change the meaning of your data.

Comment: Once you have overwritten the data how are you going to get the old values?

Comment: You could start with adding an [output clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to the `update` statement to capture the _before_ and _after_ values. Then use a separate query to derange _[sic]_ that data into the desired form.

Comment: If you want audit trail of data edits, review http://allenbrowne.com/AppAudit.html. You are maintaining same data in two table structures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did it like this:

```
declare @changeTime as datetime = getdate()

;WITH NEWDATA AS (
SELECT @changeTime AS modified, 'NEW' AS status, t.id AS primarykey
,columnA=IIF(len(t.columnA) = 0 OR t.columnA = '1899-12-30', s.columnA,t.ColumnA)
,columnB=IIF(len(t.columnB) = 0 OR t.columnB = '1899-12-30', s.columnB,t.columnB)
,columnC=IIF(len(t.columnC) = 0 OR t.columnC = '1899-12-30', s.columnC,t.columnC) 
FROM sourcetable s
INNER JOIN targettable t
WHERE t.columnA=IIF(len(t.columnA) = 0 OR t.columnA = '1899-12-30', s.columnA,t.ColumnA)
OR t.columnB=IIF(len(t.columnB) = 0 OR t.columnB = '1899-12-30', s.columnB,t.columnB)
OR t.columnC=IIF(len(t.columnC) = 0 OR t.columnC = '1899-12-30', s.columnC,t.columnC)
)
    
INSERT INTO tbl_CHANGES
SELECT * FROM NEWDATA

INSERT INTO tbl_CHANGES
SELECT @changeTime AS modified, 'OLD' AS status, t.id AS primarykey,* 
FROM targettable t
WHERE t.primarykey in (SELECT primarykey FROM tbl_CHANGES WHERE modified = @changeTime)

UPDATE targettable SET
 columnA=IIF(len(t.columnA) = 0 OR t.columnA = '1899-12-30', s.columnA,t.ColumnA)
,columnB=IIF(len(t.columnB) = 0 OR t.columnB = '1899-12-30', s.columnB,t.columnB)
,columnC=IIF(len(t.columnC) = 0 OR t.columnC = '1899-12-30', s.columnC,t.columnC)
FROM sourcetable s
LEFT JOIN targettable t
```

It stores an 'OLD' version and a 'NEW" version of each record that has changed.
It is not as nice as the solution originally envisioned but it does meet the goal of being able to see what is changed.
All of this wrapped in a single transaction of course. Putting this out not as the best or brightest (this is not production) but somebody might stumble onto this question and like an answer.